# xmlserializernamespaces add namespace to a specific element

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have an object and I would like to serialize it. I would like to add the namespaces to a specific element of the xml document. I have created several .xsd files from 1 default xml. I use XmlSerializer.

The namespace should be described in the `<sos:element`. That is what I want:

```
<env:root
  xmls:env ="httpenv"
  xmlns:sos="httpsos">
   <env:body>
     <sos:element 
       xmlns:abc="" <--------------my namespaces are located in <sos:element
       ...
```

if I use something like

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("abc", "httpabc");
ns.add....
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();   
serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, ObjectToSerialize, ns);
```

I will get the following

```
<env:root
  xmls:env ="httpenv"
  xmlns:sos="httpsos"
  xmlns:abc="" <-------------I do not want it here; I want it in <sos:element
   <env:body>
     <sos:element> 
      ...
```

Is there a way to specify where (in which element) I would like to have my namespaces declared or are they all declared in the root element?

Comment: How are the XSD files relevant for the answer to your question?

Comment: The mention of xsd files, was just a small sideinfo. Btw, why did I get a downvote..

Comment: 4 years later and i got a similar question, and your question seems legitimate, don't understand the downvote either.

Comment: Maybe some trolls :) Well, let's upvote the question!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From XML perspective, it doesn't matter where the XML namespace is defined. If you need the XML namespace declaration at a particular place, there's probably something wrong with the component that parses the XML.

Well, anyway, this is what I came up with:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace XMLNamespaceChangeSerialization
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var serialize = Serialize();
            Console.WriteLine(serialize);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static string Serialize()
        {
            var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("env", "httpenv");
            // Don't add it here, otherwise it will be defined at the root element
            // ns.Add("sos", "httpsos");
            var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (RootClass), "httpenv");
            serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, new RootClass(), ns);
            return stringWriter.ToString();
        }
    }


    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "root")]
    public class RootClass
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "body", Namespace = "httpenv")]
        public BodyClass body = new BodyClass();
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class BodyClass
    {
        [XmlElement( ElementName = "element", Namespace = "httpsos")]
        public SOSClass element = new SOSClass();
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class SOSClass
    {
        // This will be used by XML serializer to determine the namespaces
        [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
        public XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(
                    new[] { new XmlQualifiedName("sos", "httpsos"), });
    }
}
```

Comment: Just add: ``ns.Add("sos", "httpsos");`` to your ``Serialize()``. And
in your SOSClass change the ``public XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { new XmlQualifiedName("sos", "httpsos"), });`` to ``public XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { new XmlQualifiedName("abc", "WriteNamespaceHere"), });`` and you are done

Comment: @eyalsn: thanks for the hint. Indeed, I explained how to move the `sos` namespace to somewhere else. With the concept behind it, the reader should now be able to move any namespace anywhere.

Comment: @ThomasWeller can i do what you have shown without editing the original Class ? Because my Class is generated by svcUtil using a wsdl definition and i don't what to touch it, instead i want to manipulate the Serializer object such that when it serialises,  it adds a prefix / namespace to a specific element. Is this possible ?

Comment: @joedotnot: not sure if it can be done via the serializer. You could apply a transformation on the serialized XML which does that. Maybe you want to ask your own question here on SO.